# Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 1297: (null)

Tags: custom-keyboard

When this error occurs? I'm trying to create custom keyboard with image on it and getting this error while loading the image.

Comment: You properly change something in plist and don't reset simulator

Comment: I'm having the same error message in my custom keyboard as well. In my case, my storyboard doesn't get loaded in the input view in my custom keyboard and only the Next Keyboard button is loaded which is included there by default. I also only have a single button with leading and top constraints only.

Comment: In my case there was an error in my plist: I added a property to the target's plist it did not like (NSExtensionPrincipalClass)